# Обновление содержимого страницы без перезагрузки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, frontend

Как реализовать обновление страницы без ее перезагрузки, но с обновлением url(адресной строки) страницы?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: да, можно вместе использовать ajax c window.history.pushState https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

Comment: Данный метод обновляет url страницы, а как организовать обновление данных на странице без перезагрузки. Буду признателен за пример в песочнице.